# How to display long and dry text's?

Tags: text, settings, legal, consent

How would you display your users really long text's that are dry and they don't really want to read?

Context: 
We have a relatively big website with a area for our paying customers.
Since the laws in europe changed we need to adjust our consent-process.

This means that when before you, as a user could just enter your Name + Email and receive a newsletter if you wish, you now have to explicit give consent.

We have like 8 "big" categories which are named like "Advertisement" and have sub-points like "Newsletter", "Sales news", "Business news" etc.

Our legal department told us we need to provide the users the legal text's with every point they can choose to give consent.

**I thought about something like this:**

[image]

Hitting the Info-Icon will show a tooltip with a small summarized text of the legal text, which is written like a non-legal text if you know what i mean, below that text inside of the tooltip users will find a "Read entire text in a new tab"-Link which would open a new tab in their browser and display the whole legal text.

Im not a fan of opening stuff in new tabs but since those texts can be up to a whole A4 page long i don't really think displaying it in the same screen makes much sense.

Do you have any other recommendations or comments regarding my "solution"?

I appreciate it.

Comment: Have you run this solution by your legal team? I've been given legal text before and was specifically told that it had to be put in the users' face (i.e. not behind a tooltip or a collapsible section or anything) so they couldn't miss it and claim it was never shown to them. I find that, unfortunately, in these situations legal requirements tend to trump good user experience...

Comment: Yes i have, right now they aren't 100% sure what is legal and what is not since its kind of new territory for them as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the long text is conveying legal information and is necessary to show then the fact about it being 'legally necessary to Agree with' is more important for a user than reading the entire text. Of course, they may choose to read the document, in which case, I'd give an option to download the legal info as PDF like it happens in the most Installation process.

[image]

Additionally, we can show links to the important sections of the document that you think is crucial for them.

Answer (score 0):

GDPR requires that full text is accessible and that the **user gives explicit consent**. See https://www.eugdpr.org/.

The General Data Protection Regulations in the EU are so extensive that some companies are offering packaged compliance services, see, for example: https://www.evidon.com/solutions/gdpr/.

BTW, did you know you have to provide a map of the marketing tags used on your site and their third-party data consumers? To see how many tags may be active on your site, download the Ghostery Chrome plug-in -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery-%E2%80%93-privacy-ad-blo/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij?hl=en. Kind of scary, when you think how little of your online life is actually private.